# Другое действие по повторному клику на кнопке

Tags: javascript, form

Есть форма поиска. По нажатию на кнопку, появляется input с возможностью ввода поискового запроса. После того, как пользователь введет поисковый запрос, нужно чтобы повторное нажатие по кнопке приводило к отправке формы.

```js
var buttonSearch = document.querySelector(".site-nav__button-search");
var fieldSearch = document.querySelector(".site-nav__search-field");

buttonSearch.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  fieldSearch.classList.add("site-nav__search-field--show");
});
```

```css
.site-nav__search {
  display: flex;
}

.site-nav__search-field {
  display: none;
}

.site-nav__search-field--show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="site-nav__search" action="search.php" method="post">
  <input class="site-nav__search-field" name="search" type="text">
  <button class="site-nav__button-search">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var buttonSearch = document.querySelector(".site-nav__button-search"),
    fieldSearch = document.querySelector(".site-nav__search-field"),
    flag;
buttonSearch.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  !flag && evt.preventDefault();
  fieldSearch.classList[!flag ? 'add' : 'remove']("site-nav__search-field--show");
  flag = !flag;
});
```

```css
.site-nav__search {
  display: flex;
}

.site-nav__search-field {
  display: none;
}

.site-nav__search-field--show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="site-nav__search" action="search.php" method="post">
  <input class="site-nav__search-field" name="search" type="text">
  <button class="site-nav__button-search">Поиск</button>
</form>
```